# Neo4j query response is very slow even I have warm the cache

Tags: neo4j

In my neo4j database, there are **36000000+ node**, **31000000+ relationships**, **2 billion properties**.

The index was created, and after start neo4j, I warm the cache as:  https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/warm-the-cache-to-improve-performance-from-cold-start/

But when I run a cypher query the first time, it's very slow,about **30 second**; and the consume time drops to **600 ms** after first query.

The same query but change the different entity,it also cost **30 second** .

Any advice to improve?

ps:

**Index:**

index on :area1(effectiveTime)
index on :labelA(objId)

**neo4j configuration:**

heap:20g, pagecache:15g,
database size is 7.9 G

**cypher query :**

```
match (v1:labelA {objId:"XXXX"})-[r1:ARelationship]->(loc1:area1)<-
   [r2:ARelationship]-(tmp:labelA ) 
   with collect (DISTINCT tmp.objId) as need1,v1,loc1,loc1.effectiveTime as T1
   match (v1)-[r1:BRelationship]->(loc2:area1)<-[r2:BRelationship]-(tmp:labelA )
   where tmp.objId in need1 and loc2.effectiveTime = T1
   with collect(tmp.objId)[..10] as top10,loc1,loc2
   return loc1.objId,loc2.objId ,top10, loc2.effectiveTime as time 
   order by time
```

[image]

Comment: can you share your queries , contrainst & index and your neo4j configuratoin (heap, pagecache) ?

Comment: I used collect(), is this the reason of slow?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the PROFILE plan of this query (after expanding all elements of the plan)?

Comment: this picture is a example, it costs 15 s . thanks